# Are ref and out in C# the same a pointers in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, unsafe, ref

I just made a Swap routine in C# like this:

```
static void Swap(ref int x, ref int y)
{
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}
```

It does the same thing that this C++ code does:

```
void swap(int *d1, int *d2)
{
    int temp=*d1;
    *d1=*d2;
    *d2=temp;
}
```

So are the `ref` and `out` keywords like pointers for C# without using `unsafe` code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're more limited. You can say ++ on a pointer, but not on a `ref` or `out`.

---

**EDIT** Some confusion in the comments, so to be absolutely clear: the point here is to compare with the capabilities of pointers. You can't perform the same operation as `ptr++` on a `ref`/`out`, i.e. make it address an adjacent location in memory. It's true (but irrelevant here) that you can perform the equivalent of `(*ptr)++`, but that would be to compare it with the capabilities of *values*, not pointers.

---

It's a safe bet that they are internally just pointers, because the stack doesn't get moved and C# is carefully organised so that `ref` and `out` always refer to an active region of the stack.

---

**EDIT** To be absolutely clear again (if it wasn't already clear from the example below), the point here is not that `ref`/`out` can *only* point to the stack. It's that *when* it points to the stack, it is guaranteed by the language rules not to become a dangling pointer. This guarantee is necessary (and relevant/interesting here) because the stack just discards information in accordance with method call exits, with no checks to ensure that any referrers still exist.

Conversely when `ref`/`out` refers to objects in the GC heap it's no surprise that those objects are able to be kept alive as long as necessary: the GC heap is designed precisely for the purpose of retaining objects for any length of time required by their referrers, and provides pinning (see example below) to support situations where the object must not be moved by GC compacting.

---

If you ever play with interop in unsafe code, you will find that `ref` is very closely related to pointers. For example, if a COM interface is declared like this:

```
HRESULT Write(BYTE *pBuffer, UINT size);
```

The interop assembly will turn it into this:

```
void Write(ref byte pBuffer, uint size);
```

And you can do this to call it (I believe the COM interop stuff takes care of pinning the array):

```
byte[] b = new byte[1000];
obj.Write(ref b[0], b.Length);
```

In other words, `ref` to the first byte gets you access to all of it; it's apparently a pointer to the first byte.

Comment: You can `++` on a `ref` argument just fine, but it doesn't mean the same thing.

Comment: Also, "`ref` and `out` always refer to an active region of the stack" is just completely wrong.  Your own example creates a `ref` into an object on the gc heap.

Answer (score 6):

Reference parameters in C# can be used to replace *one* use of pointers, yes. But not all.

Another common use for pointers is as a means for iterating over an array. Out/ref parameters can not do that, so no, they are not "the same as pointers".

Answer (score 3):

`ref` and `out` are only used with function arguments to signify that the argument is to be passed by reference instead of value. In this sense, yes, they are somewhat like pointers in C++ (more like references actually). Read more about it in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The nice thing about using *out* is that you're guaranteed that the item will be assigned a value -- you will get a compile error if not.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I'd compare them to C++ references rather than pointers.  Pointers, in C++ and C, are a more general concept, and references will do what you want.

All of these are undoubtedly pointers under the covers, of course.

Comment: Syntactically they actually resemble pointers more closely, because you have to prepend `ref`, just as you have to prepend `&` to get a pointer in C/C++.

Comment: (I mean at the calling site.)

Comment: So they're really somewhere in the middle (as you don't have to dereference it when reading/writing to it).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is Yes (similar functionality, but not exactly the same mechanism).
As a side note, if you use FxCop to analyse your code, using `out` and `ref` will result in a "Microsoft.Design" error of "CA1045:DoNotPassTypesByReference."

Answer (score 1):

While comparisons are in the eye of the beholder...I say no.  'ref' changes the **calling convention** but not the **type** of the parameters.  In your C++ example, d1 and d2 are of type int*.  In C# they are still Int32's, they just happen to be passed by reference instead of by value.

By the way, your C++ code doesn't really swap its inputs in the traditional sense.  Generalizing it like so:

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T *d1, T *d2)
{
    T temp = *d1;
    *d1 = *d2;
    *d2 = temp;
}
```

...won't work unless all types T have copy constructors, and even then will be much more inefficient than swapping pointers.

Comment: I don't think your analogy quite works; consider `int *` versus `const int *` in C++. Const is a qualifier that restricts the use of the type it applies to, effectively turning it into a different type. But when C++ is compiled to IL, `const` is turned into a kind of custom modifier on a type rather than defining a different type in the CLI type system. This shows that "type" in the language is separate from "type" in the runtime. In the same way `ref` limits what you can do with the object (you can't capture it in a lambda, for example), and this is part of C#'s type system, though not CLI's.