# What are the different ways to pass a byte array from c++ to a c# assembly?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I would like to know the different approaches that can be used to pass a byte array from c++ to c# and their performance characteristics. I would ideally like to pass a pointer to a byte array in an unmanaged heap to the C# assembly and avoid any copy operation.

Comment: Do you want to return a pointer to a C# caller? Or have the C++ code call a C# method?

Comment: Have the c++ code call a C# method.

Comment: you can try refering to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167342/are-ref-and-out-in-c-sharp-the-same-a-pointers-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're calling a C# method from unmanaged C++ using something like [Reverse P/Invoke](http://tigerang.blogspot.com/2008/09/reverse-pinvoke.html), you can just pass the pointer. The C# code should accept the pointer as `IntPtr` or `UIntPtr`, which it can then treat as an unmanaged array.

There are a number of ways to access the data behind that pointer once you pass it to the C# code. You can use [Unsafe Code and Pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx), which is probably the highest performance if you're partying on individual bytes.

If you want to treat it as a stream of bytes, you could use [UnmanagedMemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream.aspx).

Or, you can use the `Marshal.Copy` and `Marshal.Read` (many variants) methods to read different data types at different areas within that buffer.

None of the above require any copying of data other than the pointer itself between the C++ and C# code.

There are undoubtedly other ways to access the memory from C# that I haven't listed above. The gist of it is that passing an array of bytes either way is pretty painless.

Comment: I was hoping to use COM interop to call the C# methods. Something similar to this post - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16206/Call-C-code-from-C-and-read-an-array-of-struct-whi

Comment: @SriramSubramanian: See Exposing .NET Framework Components to COM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720072(v=vs.71).aspx. You should be able to pass a byte array (that you allocate through COM) directly, and then use it as an `IntPtr` as I outlined above.

Comment: Thank you. Does this apply to char* to c# string object also?

Comment: @SriramSubramanian: No. Passing C++ `char*` and making a C# `string` is a more complex issue and that requires copying. See the `Marshal` class `PtrToString` methods (`PtrToStringAnsi`, `PtrToStringAnsi`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have pointers on C++ side and ref on the C# side. Refer the link provided in the comment.