# Some doubts about the out keyword in front of a method paramether?

Tags: c#, .net

I am pretty new in **C#** (I came from Java) and I have the following doubt.

In a class I have the declarationf of this method:

```
public List<DataModel.MaliciousCode.MaliciousSmall> getList(DataModel.MaliciousCode.MaliciousSmall model, out int totalRecords)
        {

        .............................................
        .............................................
        .............................................

        }
```

My doubt is related to the **out** keyword in the paramether list.

Reading the official documentation I have understand that this parameter is passed by reference (and that it could be not initialized).

So what exactly means? It means that in C# I have pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`out` means that when this method will be called, the parameter `totalRecords` **will** be assigned some value from the method, and that value will be available to the caller.

[out parameter modifier (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx)

> The out keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. This is
>   like the ref keyword, except that ref requires that the variable be
>   initialized before it is passed. To use an out parameter, both the
>   method definition and the calling method must explicitly use the out
>   keyword.

For example, if you call your method like:

```
int totalRecords; //just declaration no initialization 
var list = getList(new MaliciousSmall(), out totalRecords);
Console.WriteLine(totalRecords);// value from method.
```

at the end of method call, `totalRecords` will be assigned some value inside the method. It is **mandatory for the method `getList` to assign/initialize some value to `totalRecords`**. If  it is not assigned any value in the method, a compile time error would occur. That is the reason why `out` parameters may or many not be initialized before using in method call.

Comment: ok but is it related to something like the classic C pointer (or the classic concept of pointer as a memory address)?

Comment: @AndreaNobili, not really, pointers in C# are used in the context of [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx) code. `ref` and `out` are used for pass by reference. But unlike C, you can't use their address and manipulate in safe code. The concept is similar, but not exactly same due to nature of [Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb318664(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

inside your method, `out int totalRecords` must be assigned to any correct value depending on its type before the methods returned.

Even the `totalRecords` might be assigned to a value before calling this method (not encouraged), but the `totalRecords` still must be assigned to a value before it come out from method and other variable cannot do any value calculations or operations on it before it is assigned to any value, and this is different with other parameter modifiers such as `ref`.

For me, I might use the method return value as indication of method process, and `out` variable on other results that must come out from the method but the initialized value outside scope of the method can be ignored.  **safely handle multiple return values** with `out`

Refer to accepted answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167342/are-ref-and-out-in-c-sharp-the-same-a-pointers-in-c), obvious difference is "You can say **++** on a pointer, but **not on** a `ref` or `out`." and `ref` is very closed to **pointers** but not out.

When we checked the **Generated CIL Code difference** between ref , out and pointers in C#, we can see [this](http://realsimplecoding-internals.blogspot.com/2013/04/c-internals-ref-out-and-pointer.html).